# Saving integer matrices into a text file in matlab

Tags: matlab, text

I have a matrix `MAT_1` which is a matrix of size `400 x 3` containing symbolic variables.

I would like to accomplish the following

1. Save this `MAT_1` from workspace to a `.txt` file. I tried the usual `load`/`save`/`dlmwrite`, and it didn't work. The problem is the new lines do not get created properly or it's a chunk with no delimiters (I've tried these but didn't work as well)
2. My `MAT_1` array contains characters such as `[`, `]` which I would like to replace by blank spaces. Generally I do think by replacing, but I've realized it's annoying.
3. Also is it possible to add few lines of text before the `MAT_1` is saved to the `.txt` file?

Could anyone help with code for this particular `MAT_1` example? Thanks

Comment: `dlmwrite` sounds like the correct function to use, please post your code of how you tried it. Also please include a small example matrix and an example of *exactly* what you want the text file to contain.

Comment: so for example, i use dlmwrite('newfile.txt',eye(3)), the output in the textfile is 1,0,00,1,00,0,1 
without any new lines created between 100,010,001.

Also how do i replace the '00' by blank for example? What is the syntax